# how to set ScrollView in RecycleView

Tags: android

i will use ScrollView in RecycleView. Unfortunately, the page will scroll. But the contents of the scroll, is not scrolling

my RecyclerView code is :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#B0BEC5">

<include
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    layout="@layout/app_bar_tanz" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="@color/smiley_category">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/select_smiley"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/layer_smiley">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/main_text_smiley"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="@string/title_smiley_category"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="30dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view_sms_smiley"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    style="@style/scrollbar_shape_style"/>
```

my Design page code with ScrollView :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#f8f8f8"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="145dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

        <ScrollView
            style="@style/scrollbar_shape_style_sms_card"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sms_card_statment"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="@string/app_info_info"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/sms_card_option_layout"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp">

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:background="@color/sms_card_divid" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/sms_card_option_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/sms_card_count_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sms_card_count_image"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_chart_img"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sms_card_count_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sms_card_count_image"
                android:text="@string/sms_card_count"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="@color/sms_card_count"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sms_card_count"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sms_card_count_title"
                android:text="245"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="@color/sms_card_count"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/sms_card_share_layout"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sms_card_share_image"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_share_img"
                android:onClick="share_text_method"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/sms_card_copy_layout"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sms_card_share_layout">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sms_card_copy_image"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_copy_img"
                android:onClick="copy_text_method"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In fact, I want a scrolling TextView that is located inside the RecyclerView show it.
So that if the text does not scroll the scrollbar to scroll the whole page again.

please help me and Send the correct code

Answer (score -2, accepted):

RecyclerView is also an Listview which doesn't require scrollview. If u want to use write ontouch lisetner. It works according to your touch. 
But, avoid scrollview inside a scrollview for the better performance of application and its bad idea.....

Comment: Thank you, your thoughts and ideas of what to do to fix this?
What is your solution?

Comment: Y u need Scrollview inside recyclerview.... My solution is don't use scrollview...